# How to ssh to Live CD for remote recovery - root password issue?

Tags: ssh, live-cd, root, remote-access

Is there an automatic way to SSH to a machine that booted from Live CD?

I have a remote server with a HDD issue and the ISP booted my machine from a Live CD.

I can SSH to the machine (lucky has the same IP) but I cannot login because I have no password.

How can I solve this problem?

If this is not possible, how can I find or configure a CD or USB stick that would allow me to do that.

Answer (score 1):

I think the LiveCD does not have the openssh server installed by default ;-(. You can verify at your home computer.
If there was an SSH server, you should be able to connect with `ubuntu` and empty password. 
You can ask them to merely run `sudo apt-get install openssh-server`.

What's your alternative?

1. You ask the ISP to go to System » Preferences » Remote Desktop in order to enable remote access. Check the options in the dialog box from your own computer so that you can give them the exact advice.
2. Then, ask the ISP to log in to a Google Chat account that you will provide.
3. From your own account (with Google Chat), find that *ISP user account* and right click on it. Select Remote Administer. Press Enter, and you connected to the LiveCD using the GUI.

Comment: Sorry, but I am looking for a solution that would require minimial intervention for the ISP. Mainly I want to have a stick or CD. Something that will work even if you do not have a monitor or keyboard on the computer (assuming that you have a DHCP sever on the lan).